# How to extract JSON Data to apply Dynamically in UITableView in swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I'm confused with parsing the data from JSON. Actually, i  extracted the whole data. But i am confused that how to apply it to table View rows. so, How to extract JSON Data and Apply it to dynamic `tableView` rows? lot of thanks in advance.

The JSON Data from URL is given below,

```
{
  "main_result": "1",
  "event_listing": [
    {
      "event_details": "Omega Events",
      "pdf_url": "http://portal.shineevents.co.in/portal/assets/uploads/pdf/",
      "modified_date": "2016-06-22 14:17:02"
    },
    {
      "event_details": "Cobra Events",
      "pdf_url": "http://portal.shineevents.co.in/portal/assets/uploads/pdf/",
      "modified_date": "2016-06-22 14:17:18"
    },
    {
      "event_details": "Kovai Events",
      "pdf_url": "http://portal.shineevents.co.in/portal/assets/uploads/pdf/",
      "modified_date": "2016-06-22 14:23:45"
    }
  ]
}
```

Code I have try

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{

    var labels = ["Taylor Swift","Eminem","Avlirl","Michael"] /* i use dummy array now*/

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        retrieveDataFromJASON()
    }

    func retrieveDataFromJASON()
    {
        let URL = NSURL(string: "http://portal.shineevents.co.in/portal/api_load/app_load_call")
        let requestURL = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)
        requestURL.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let postString = "api=event_list"

        requestURL.addValue("123456", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-API-KEY")
        requestURL.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(requestURL) { data, response, error in

            guard error == nil && data != nil else {
                print("error=\(error)")

                return

            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {

                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")

                print("response = \(response)")


            }

            let responseString2 = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

            print(responseString2) /*prints whole JSON Data*/


            let events = responseString2["event_listing"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]

            for eventName in events!
            {
                print(eventName["event_details"])

                /* Prints:
                    Optional(Omega Events)
                    Optional(Cobra Events)
                    Optional(Kovai Events)  // How to print only First event only
                */

            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return labels.count  // How to use event_details.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableCell
        cell.titles.text = labels[indexPath.row]  // how to use event_details[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare instance variable of type `[[String: AnyObject]]` and use that with `UITableViewDelegate` method like below

```
var events : [[String: AnyObject]] = [[String: AnyObject]]()
```

Now initialize this events object when you get response and after that reload `tableView`.

```
self.events = responseString2["event_listing"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Now use this `events` object with `UITableView` methods

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return events.count  // How to use event_details.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableCell
    cell.titles.text = events[indexPath.row]["event_details"] as? String 
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Wow! Great Mr. Nirav .thanks for clear explanation. thankz lot :) :)

Comment: Welcome mate Happy Coding :)

Comment: hi Mr.Nirav i need one more help. As well as i updating your answer on my code.when I click the Button then the tableView opened . But the Table View Does not shown any Data. after that i press anywhere in table View then the table view shows number of rows with the Retrieved JSON Data. How do i fix it?

Comment: Please update the new code so i can understand what problem you are facing.

Comment: Update this question or add new post and give me the link of the new post  here

Comment: this is  my Updated Post Mr.Nirav.  [Tableview reloads But Not shown if I not Click anywhere on ViewController in swift 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593023/tableview-reloads-but-not-shown-if-i-not-click-anywhere-on-viewcontroller-in-swi)

Answer (score -2):

You can get JSON data with converting it into NSData. Check my answer please : [How to save JSON data from a POST Request into dictionary with Swifty Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559403/how-to-save-json-data-from-a-post-request-into-dictionary-with-swifty-json/38562651#38562651)

Once you have dictionary you can easly parse it. See this: http://tech.ustwo.com/2014/08/01/ios-swift-dictionaries/

Also you should create your own cell on tableview so you can add your attributes to cells. Follow this tutorial :https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello. Posting links does not make a good answer. Either you post an actual answer to the question, with code and explanations, or you can *flag* the question as "duplicate" if you think it already has an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Actually this answers seems good. but i can't understand. Because , i don't know Objective - C and i don't know how to user your method to my problem. Anyway Thanks for the response Mr. Firats :) :) :D :D

Comment: ohh okay okay! thanks again for your opinion. Duplicate Mean? Already asked in stack over flow ah? OR This question has answer so, no need answer ah?

Comment: @MohanSingh Duplicate means "this question already has an answer". This is because SO does not want to have duplicated content, so users can flag questions as duplicate as soon as they see one, instead of answering the same thing again and again.

Comment: @MohanSingh Also, you say "this answers seems good. but i can't understand. Because , i don't know Objective - C and i don't know how to user your method" so actually, no, this answer is not good. ;)

Comment: Oh Okay k. becouse i know only few words in english! I will  try to improve my answers.