# Tableview reloads But Not shown if I not Click anywhere on ViewController in swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift

I have problem with `UITableView`. Actually, Below Code is Works fine else tableview. In my project, when i click the button, then new view controller was opened. The new View controller had a `UITableView` to load tableview data dynamically from JSON. Problem is the tableView data does not shown when i click the button. It appears empty white screen. Then I Click anywhere in view controller, then suddenly the tableview datas are shown. Ho do i fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Code I have try

```
import UIKit

class Events: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        retrieveDataFromJASON()
    }

    var events: [[String: AnyObject]] = [[String: AnyObject]]()
    var dateAndTime: [[String: AnyObject]] = [[String: AnyObject]]()

    func retrieveDataFromJASON() {

        let URL = NSURL(string: "http://portal.shineevents.co.in/portal/api_load/app_load_call")

        let requestURL = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)
        requestURL.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let postString = "api=event_list"
        requestURL.addValue("123456", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-API-KEY")
        requestURL.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(requestURL) { data, response, error in

            guard error == nil && data != nil else {
                print("error=\(error)")

                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString2 = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

            //print(responseString2) /*prints whole JSON Data*/
            self.events = (responseString2["event_listing"] as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            //print(self.events[0]["event_details"])
        }

        task.resume()
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return events.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("eventCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventTableViewCell

        cell.eventName.text = events[indexPath.row]["event_details"] as? String
        cell.eventDate.text = events[indexPath.row]["modified_date"] as? String
        cell.eventTime.hidden = true
        cell.rowNumber.text = String(indexPath.row + 1)

        return cell
    }
}
```

screenshot1: At First Not shown any data(shown after the 15seconds)
[image]

sceenshot2: The table view shows data suddenly when i click it.( below 2 seconds)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the activity indicator in your view to show that it is processing request and also reload the `tableView` in main thread.

First add activityIndicator instance and these 2 method's in your viewController

```
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

func activityIndicatorBegin() {
    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,50,50))
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    disableUserInteraction()

    greyView = UIView()
    greyView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
    greyView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    greyView.alpha = 0.5
    self.view.addSubview(greyView)
}

func activityIndicatorEnd() {
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    enableUserInteraction()
    self.greyView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Now call this method in your `retrieveDataFromJASON` like this way

```
func retrieveDataFromJASON() {
    self.activityIndicatorBegin()
    let URL = NSURL(string: "http://portal.shineevents.co.in/portal/api_load/app_load_call")
    let requestURL = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)
    requestURL.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "api=event_list"

    requestURL.addValue("123456", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-API-KEY")
    requestURL.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(requestURL) { data, response, error in
        activityIndicatorEnd()
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            print("error=\(error)")

            return

        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }
        let responseString2 = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)
        //print(responseString2) /*prints whole JSON Data*/
        self.events = (responseString2["event_listing"] as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
             self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        //print(self.events[0]["event_details"])
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

**Note -** If you want to use these indicator in more than one controller than for that check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38457815/6433023) it will help you.

Comment: Wow great answer.Even the adding of activity indicator is superb.thanks Mr.Nirav :)

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to make the updation on the UI thread. For that you have to place call on the main queue, which you can get using dispatch_async(). so, you have to do like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.table.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: it works! thanks Mr.Mayank Baiswar! small change from my question in this answer `self.tableView.reloadData()` :D

Comment: ohh sorry! i meant the IBOutlet you made of tableView.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to dispatch that update on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    self.events = (responseString2["event_listing"] as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

From the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:)

> The completion handler to call when the load request is complete. This handler is executed on the delegate queue.

Comment: Just putting self.tableView.reloadData() in the main queue block should be enough.